# Apply css to parent if they have more than x children

Tags: html, css

I would like to apply css (`break-inside: avoid;`) to any parent div who has more than x children.
Here is an example:

```html
<div class="section">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

If the section has, for example, less than 4 children I want to use `break-inside: avoid;`. Otherwise `break-inside: auto;`. I tried with nth-child/last-child without success

Thanks

Comment: Not really cause I dont want a fixed number but a min/max number

Comment: The main takeaway from the duplicate question I posted is that `styles cannot be applied to a parent node based on the number of children it has. However, styles can be applied to the children nodes based on the number of siblings they have.` However, javascript is able to detect the number of children a div has, and could conditionally apply a CSS class to that div.

Comment: So does it mean that it's only possible with js? I'm not sure if js will work in my case cause I use raw html that I assign to the innerHtml property

Comment: CSS is content unaware. It cannot detect how many children elements there are and then add styling. What you can do is set a class on the containing element if it meets that criteria using whatever method you are using to generate the markup.

Comment: Thanks. Will need to do something in js then